# Why is open_process_full not returning the stdout contents of the externam process I run?

Tags: ocaml

I want to run an external program and collect the data from its stdout. I tried doing

```
let () =
  let (sout, sin, serr) = Unix.open_process_full "echo" [|"echo"; "hello"; "world"|] in
  let line = input_line sout in
  Printf.printf "read \"%s\"\n" line
```

But I am getting an empty string back:

```
 read ""
```

I was expecting to get

```
 read "hello world"
```

I noticed that I get the desired result if I use open_process_in instead of open_process_full. Why are they behaving differently?

```
let sout = Unix.open_process_in "echo hello world" in
```

Comment: this depends on how are you writing to this process, I mean, show us how you put this "hello world" into process

Comment: I'm not writing anything to the process I create. I am just running `/bin/echo` with "hello" and "world" as the argv parameters and trying to read what it prints (or so I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter to `open_process_full` is for environment variables, not for argv. If you want to call a subprocess with an argv array then use `create_process` instead:

```
let (pr1, pw1) = Unix.pipe () in
let (pr2, pw2) = Unix.pipe () in
let _pid = Unix.create_process "/bin/echo" [|"echo"; "hello"; "world"|] pr1 pw2 Unix.stderr) in
let echo_in = Unix.out_channel_of_descr pw1 in
let echo_out = Unix.in_channel_of_descr pr2 in
let line = input_line echo_out in
Printf.printf "read \"%s\"\n" line
```

Comment: BTW this is a good hack to expand the tilde char in path names to the home directory of the/a user.

Comment: @Str exactly wrong, for tilde expansion I need the shell, like in Unix.open_process_in